# A small problem at laptop-mode-tool

Tags: 13.10, laptop

`vas@LenovoZ580:~$ sudo laptop_mode
[sudo] password for vas: 
Laptop mode 
enabled, not active [unchanged]`

What Does it mean?
I had TLP and have removed it and the problem wasn't solved. What I can try?

Answer (score 0):

It is just active or not active based on whether your laptop is plugged into AC or running on battery.

If on battery then the command turns active.